# Django 1.8 migration weirdness

Tags: django, django-1.8

Django 1.8 doesn't seem to like my app name - "orders".

When I create a new Django project using 1.8, regardless of database type (Postgres or SQLite) sync my initial database to add all of the Django core tables. Everything works as expected.

I can create an app module using just about any other name, but when I do:

```
$ python manage.py startapp orders
```

add `orders` to `INSTALLED_APPS` and then add a basic model such as:

```
from django.db import models

@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Order(models.Model):
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    account = models.ForeignKey(Account)
    is_complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta():
        app_label = 'Orders'
        ordering = ['-created_on']

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Order #{} for {}'.format(self.pk, self.account)
```

and then do:

```
$ python manage.py makemigrations
```

I get:

```
No changes detected in app 'orders'
```

I have tried Python 2.7.8 and Python 3.4. I've tried different virtual envs, and I get the exact same result, no matter what I call the Django project. If I even include "_orders" anywhere in the name of the app module the exact same result will happen.

I've cleared out my `.pyc` files countless times. I've dropped my database and re-created it. I have no idea what's going on, but migrations worked great for a huge 1.7.7 project I just finished.

Here's the relevant portions of my settings. Please let me know if you need anything else:

```
DEBUG = True

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'myapp',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '5432'
    }
}

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'accounts',
    'animals',
    'lib',
    'orders',
)
```

Anyone have any ideas? I'm at a a loss.

Comment: What's the output of `python -c "import orders; print(orders.__path__)"`? Can you also show your settings file? An app named `orders` works fine for me.

Comment: Sorry for the delay getting back to you. The output is: `['orders']`. I will add the relevant portions of my settings.

Comment: That looks all good. Can you import the model in a shell and does it contain anything in `MyModel._meta.get_fields()`? Also, are there any files in `orders/migrations/`, and what's in them?

Comment: Yes, I can import the `Order` model and call `.get_fields()`: `(<django.db.models.fields.AutoField: id>, <django.db.models.fields.DateTimeField: created_on>, <django.db.models.fields.related.ForeignKey: account>)`

Comment: The migrations directory for `orders` currently only contains an `__init__.py` file

Comment: Is your model located/imported in `orders.models`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75002/discussion-between-brandon-and-knbk).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your app label is uppercased - it is not recognized as the lowercased app `orders` as it appears in your `INSTALLED_APPS`.